# Error in VB macro after updating from Excel 2007 to 2013

Tags: vba, excel

I have VB macro designed for Excel 2007. Now Excel is updated to 2013 macros are not working and showing different errors.

This is macro which collects different sheets and analyses it to give final output:

```
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        "Sheet3!R1C1:R64999C14", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion12).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="Sheet4!R3C1", TableName:="PivotTable2", DefaultVersion 
        :=xlPivotTableVersion12
```

It is showing the debug error.

Can any one help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to record this in 2013?
Because in 2010, it look like this :

```
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        "Feuil1!R1C1:R6C2", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14).CreatePivotTable _
        TableDestination:="Feuil4!R3C1", TableName:="Tableau croisé dynamique1", _
        DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion14
```

So i think `DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion14` might be your issue, take a look at the record in 2013, it might be different than `14` even if `12` is also working with 2010.

Comment: Hi, i tried to change the version, but the error is on sheets ("Sheet2"). select.  Columns("P:P").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Range("N7:P11").Select
    Selection.Cut
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Range("H7").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("H6").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Country"
    Range("I6").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "eCRF Pages"
    Range("J6").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Percentage"
    Range("H6:J6").Select

Comment: For inline code, use " ` " (AltGr+7 on azerty, Left from 1 (under ~) on qwerty)
And your (displayed at least) code has nothing to do with creating pivot tables...